# RSAP package to connect to SAP through R (windows)

Tags: r, package, saprfc, netweaver

I'd need to be able to grab data straight from into R without going through using its GUI. I've found that the RSAP package seems to be exactly what I'm looking for.

I followed the steps recommended by Piers and Alvaro Tejada Galindo (made it work on windows environment) and here is where I'm stuck:

- managed to compile the RSAP package
- managed to install it
- everything is looking in good shape when I run `library(RSAP)`
- whatever i try in the `RSAPConnect` command, my R session crashes without any log or tools to be able to debug.

Of course I've tried a few combinations of arguments in this command, but in every single case it still crashed without me knowing why. It does not matter whether i enter a valid `ashost` or just `aaa` for instance, still crashes...

Here is the code I was thinking would work (of course I added stars in there):

```
conn <- RSAPConnect(ashost = "*****.****.com", sysnr = "00", client = "410",
           user = "*****", passwd = "*********", TRACE = "3")
```

Has anyone experienced something similar ? I don't even know in which direction to look to try and make this work. In fact I'd have expected some error message like "server could not be reach" for instance should the ashost not be right, but none of that happens.

I'd appreciate any assistance on this.

Thanks ahead for your support.
Kind regards

Comment: If you are working with RStudio, have a look [here](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/200554756-RStudio-Application-Logs)

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I do indeed, and it's giving me this : `31 Jul 2017 14:41:10 [rsession-***] ERROR system error 32 (The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process) [path=C:/pagefile.sys]; OCCURRED AT: time_t rstudio::core::FilePath::lastWriteTime() const C:\Users\Administrator\rstudio\src\cpp\core\FilePath.cpp:586; LOGGED FROM: time_t rstudio::core::FilePath::lastWriteTime() const C:\Users\Administrator\rstudio\src\cpp\core\FilePath.cpp:586`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some talking with Piers Harding, it appears that the segfault happens because of some code changes between previous version and version 3.x, which I use.

M. Alvaro Tejada Galindo also tried to use RSAP on a windows machine like me, but if you read [his post](https://blogs.sap.com/2012/06/21/analytics-with-sap-and-r-windows-version/comment-page-1/#comment-384871), you'll see that he was using R 2.15.0 at the time.

Unfortunately I do not have the skills to locate these changes and make the required adjustments within the RSAP code.

Piers did confirm though that RSAP is still working great using R latest build for linux.

Lastly, for those like me who struggled to find the NW RFC library, you can find it on [GitHub](https://github.com/mikewolfli/sapnwrfcsdk).

If this can help anyone...

Answer (score 0):

Well I thought I'd add this as another answer.

It is possible to code some vba embedded in an excel file to go fetch stuff into SAP. The interesting part is that I just ran into some code to run a specific vba macro from a specific excel file, all from R :

```
# Open a specific workbook in Excel:
xlApp <- COMCreate("Excel.Application")
xlWbk <- xlApp$Workbooks()$Open("C:\\Excel_file.xlsm")

# Run the macro called "MyMacro"
vxlApp$Run("MyMacro")

# Close the workbook (and save it) and quit the app:
xlWbk$Close(TRUE)
vxlApp$Quit()

# Release resources:
rm(xlWbk, xlApp)
```

So in the end, if your macro is set up to grab and store the SAP data, all you have to do next is just read this file using XLConnect or any other package as you'd normally do, and you're all set !